# systemverilog comparing two ways to wait signal; 1) @( clock iff condition), 2) while( ! condition) @(clock);

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I am looking for some intuitive understanding of systemverilog method of waiting for certain signal on the interface for 1) capturing transaction in a monitor, or 2) driving a transaction in response to some signal from DUT. Let's assume that DUT is asserting ready signal and driver has to drive two data beats (values of 1 and 2) back to back while asserting valid signal so that DUT would know when to capture data.

There are two methods of waiting for  the ready single from the DUT that I know of; 1) one is iff conditioned clock event, and the other is 2) consuming clock while some signal is not true (e.g., ready is low). The testbench code can be found [EDA playground (line 37 of my_driver.sv)](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/39DD).

The first method is using `@(posedge dut_vif.clock iff(dut_vif.ready ==  1));` 
and the second method is using `while( ! dut_vif.ready) @(posedge dut_vif.clock);` and there is single clock difference between two methods as shown in the waveform. My best understanding is --

`@(posedge dut_vif.clock iff(dut_vif.ready ==  1));`

This method is waiting for the clock rise event 'on the condition' of ready == 1. Therefore, data and valid are driven high on 25ns.

`while( ! dut_vif.ready) @(posedge dut_vif.clock);`

On the other hand, this statement means that simulation should consume clock while ready is low. However this interpretation and the actual behavior of systemverilog is very different. At 15ns, ready signal goes high and the valid and data are driven at the same cycle. My understanding is that at 15ns, the ready should be still captured as low by the testbench, and simulation should consume one clock. Therefore, the second method should behave just like the first method.

Can I get some interpretation on how to make sense of this difference?

I am  attaching waveform here.

[image: waveform comparison of two methods]

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because of hidden delta delay inside the call to `get_next_item()` Even though the time is still at 15, `counter` and thus `ready` now have their *new* values after returning from the call. Using `iff` gives you a clearer sampling of values w.r.t the clock edge. It also avoids problems when `!ready` is `x` because that evaluates to false.

Comment: For the `while(! dut_vif.ready) @(posedge dut_vif.clock);` case, it looks like that the checking of ready comes before the @(posedge clock). However, it may be true that  the real sequence of operation is like; 1) first wake up the process from @(posedge dut_vif.clock), which was blocked from the previous cycle, 2) perform the checking of dut_vif.ready. At 15ns, after the @(posedge dut_vif.clock), the ready is high and it causes the process to exit the while loop and drive the valid high at the same cycle. What do you think dave?

Comment: @dave_59 I can also imagine that it's slightly faster as it only wakes up when ready is truly high. Specman works via callbacks and you would want to minimize the amount of switches between the HDL simulator and Specman. I could imagine an SV simulator works similarly. The cost of switching might be lower, though, since it's the same engine.

Comment: @rosepark222 You can see the difference the first time entering the loop. The check comes first and `ready` is already 1. So there is no waiting for the clock.

Comment: @TudorTimi There is no *swtiching* between HDL and testbench in SystemVerilog. That was part of the motivation behind it.

Answer (score 0):

```
@(event iff (expression));
```

is equivalent to

```
do @event; while (!expression);
```

not

```
while (!expression); @event;
```

as Dave mentioned at [here](http://forums.accellera.org/topic/4529-iff-usage-as-a-mechanism-for-waiting/?tab=comments#comment-11190), maybe he forget it. That's why you missed one clock cycle.